# How to change the search options for Smartfield?

Tags: sapui5

I have the SmartField defined as follows:

```xml
<sf:SmartField id="myVariableID" value="{path: 'Variable'}">
    <sf:configuration>
        <sf:Configuration controlType="dropDownList" displayBehaviour="descriptionAndId"/>
    </sf:configuration>
</sf:SmartField>
```

And a dictionary attached to it:

```xml
<Annotations Target="service.dictionary/Variable">
    <Annotation Term="Common.Text" Path="VariableName"/>
</Annotations>

<Annotations Target="service.entity/Variable">
    <Annotation Term="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.TextArrangement" EnumMember="com.sap.vocabularies.UI.v1.TextArrangementType/TypeFirst"/>
    <Annotation Term="Common.ValueList">
        <Record Type="Common.ValueListType">
            <PropertyValue Property="CollectionPath" String="dictionarySet"/>
            <PropertyValue Property="FetchValues" Int="1"/>
            <PropertyValue Property="Parameters">
                <Collection>
                    <Record Type="Common.ValueListparameterInOut">
                        <PropertyValue Property="LocalDataProperty" PropertyPath="Variable"/>
                        <PropertyValue Property="ValueListProperty" String="Variable"/>
                    </Record>
                    <Record Type="Common.ValueListparameterDisplayOnly">
                        <PropertyValue Property="LocalDataProperty" String="VariableName"/>
                    </Record>
                </Collection>
            </PropertyValue>
        </Record>
    </Annotation>
</Annotations>
```

The field is generated as a DropDownList that allows searching, but I would like to improve it. I would like it to be possible to search by the entered string. The standard search only works for the exact word typed, for example. i would like to find the town of Saint-Étienne (and other towns where the search string is included) after typing the string "etien" or after typing the id, which is displayed in parentheses, and if i want to search by id then i have to start the search from the parentheses, e.g. the record for the town looks as follows - Saint-Étienne (01), finding the town is only possible if I type the word from the beginning and the id from the parenthesis. has anyone encountered a similar problem and has an idea how to affect the behavior of smartfield?

I tried to write a function that will be called for the smartfield change event, but without any results, as if simply filtering is ignored.